# Alter javascript button to onclick anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, document-ready

I am a total javascript noob.  I am having trouble changing the script I have, which is function on submit, to the script I want, which is click anywhere.  Here is me script:

Tip %:

```
<p>Split by: <input id="parties" /></p>
<p>Tip amt: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p>Total Bill: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p>Each Party: <input id="each" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>


function calculate () {

var amount = $('#amount').val();
var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
var parties = $('#parties').val();

var tip = amount * (percentage / 100)
var each=tip/parties;
var total = Number(amount) + tip;

$('#tip').val( tip.toFixed(2) );
$('#total').val( total.toFixed(2) );
$('#each').val( each.toFixed(2) );

return false;}

$('#calculator').submit( calculate );
```

I tried using document.ready and either I didn't use it right or it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "click anywhere"? Like this -> `$(document).on('click', calculate);`

Comment: "Click anywhere"? Can you define that more? Like `$(document).click()`, or maybe `$(':input').blur()` (click out of a control)?

Comment: You're not showing enough code - what is #calculator, a form? Do you want it to update fields when you click anywhere on the page, not just the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
$('#calculator').submit( calculate );
```

to this:

```
$('#calculator').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//you might not need this, but that is unclear
    calculate();
});
```

see here for some documentation on the default action prevention: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

EDIT NOTE: I am unclear in your question if this:

```
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
```

should be this perhaps:

```
<p><input id="calculator" type="submit" /></p>
```

Comment: NOTE: I make some very broad assumptions here...regarding the button and the ID etc...